# Sequelize findAll query returning incorrect results

Tags: mysql, sql, express, sequelize.js, nodemailer

I'm using **Passport, Nodemailer, Sequelize, and Express** to handle verification of user accounts who have signed up via email to the app.

To test this feature, I use **Mailinator** accounts to sign up, and send the email (along with a query string containing the user email and a uniquely-determined verification code) to the specified Mailinator address using Nodemailer. I then open the email in Nodemailer, click on the verification link, which updates the verification flag in the database and verifies the user.

This process works as I expect it to for exactly one user who signs up via email. When a second user signs up, the verification email is sent just as before with the username and unique verification codes in the query string, but this time, multiple users are being returned from the User.`findAll` query through Sequelize when the link is clicked. My query is intended to `findAll` possible matches of both email addresses and verification codes (since each user can only sign on with one email address and verification codes are unique), but for some reason the query is returning all matches from that query.

Here is some code for reference:

```
/* Sending the emails */

emails.sendActivationEmail = function(user){
    const qso = {username: user.username, activationCode: user.activationCode};
    const qs = querystring.stringify(qso);
    const from = new helper.Email(<myEmailAddress@email.com>);
    const to = new helper.Email(user.username);
    const subject = 'Welcome to My Site!';
    const content = new helper.Content('text/html', "<p> Thanks for signing up " +
    "for our psych study, please <a href=\"http://localhost:7000/users/validate/account?" + 
     qs + "\">confirm your email</a></p>");

    const mail = new helper.Mail(from, subject, to, content);

    sendMail(mail); //invokes SendGrid mail helper function
}

/* Function invoked when user clicks on verification link in email */

emails.validateUserAccount = function(req, res){
    const url = parseUrl(req.url);
    const query = querystring.parse(url.query);

    db.User.findAll({where: query}).then(function(matches){
        if(matches.length !== 1){
            res.send('error: multiple users found');
        }
        else{
            db.User.update({
                isVerified : true
            }, 
            {
                where: {
                    username: matches[0].username
                }
            });
            req.session.user = matches[0];
            res.redirect('/');
        }
    }).catch(function(err){
       console.error(err);
       res.send(err);
    });
}
```

Console statements in the validateUserAccount() function reveal that the query is exactly as I expect `({username: <emailAddress>, activationCode: <uniqueCode>})`. However, console.log statements made in the first line after the `findAll` query is executed reveal that all users are being returned from the query, which should be impossible if the WHERE query is being passed in correctly, which it looks like it is from the logged statements. Why is User.`findAll` returning incorrect results from my query?

Comment: You probably want to use `Model.findOne()` instead of `findAll()` to add `LIMIT 1` and return a single result, although this isn't your underlying problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are using the return value of `querystring.parse()`

As denoted in the Node docs:

> Note: The object returned by the querystring.parse() method does not prototypically extend from the JavaScript Object. This means that the typical Object methods such as obj.toString(), obj.hasOwnProperty(), and others are not defined and will not work.

It's likely the `where` clause expects an actual JS Object.

Further, as @doublesharp mentioned, you probably want to be fetching one row and validating it, as opposed to `findAll`ing the rows and then filtering through. Also, you should take advantage of callbacks. You're writing blocking code right now.

Comment: Looking at the documentation, there's a strong possibility that you're correct, but if I can't use querystring.parse(), how does one extract the username and activationCode to create a new object for the query then?

Comment: That's fair. Try using JSON.stringify on the parse return value, then JSON.parse it into an object then pass it in to see if that works. If not, we'll have to find another way to get it to work.

Comment: The following code worked within validateUserAccount(): var url = parseUrl(req.url);
    var parsedQs = querystring.parse(url.query);
    query = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(parsedQs));

    const code = query.activationCode;
    const name = query.username; Then I just placed code and name in the where query directly with findOne instead of findAll.